# How do I pass a variable using window.open()?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, asp.net

I would like to add some variables when my window.open function fires.

Example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('Details.aspx', 'Title'))"><%# Eval("Id").ToString) %></a>
```

I would like to pass the id number to the Details.aspx page.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it on the query string:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('Details.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Id").ToString) %>', 'Title'))"><%# Eval("Id").ToString) %></a>
```

In `Details.aspx` you will be able to get it:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the value as a query string

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('Details.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Id").ToString) %>', 'Title'))"><%# Eval("Id").ToString) %></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in the query string or fragment, and parse it on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference variables in the parent page from the child page via `window.opener`.  Your parent page would have script something like this:

```
var detailsId = 0;
function openDetails(id)
{
    detailsId = id;
    window.open('Details.aspx', 'Title');
}
```

and HTML something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(openDetails('<%# Eval("Id").ToString) %>'))">
    <%# Eval("Id").ToString) %></a>
```

And your child page could get the id in script like this:

```
var id = window.opener.detailsId;
```

enjoy!