# How do I pass parameters in window.open method

Tags: asp.net

How do I pass parameters in window.open method.

```
<table id="tblUsers" cellspacing="0" >
        <asp:Repeater ID="repUsers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;<a ID="hlUser" runat="server"  Target="_new"  onclick="return OpenWindow();" ><%# Eval("Username") %></a></td></tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>

function OpenWindow() {
    var toUsername = document.getElementById("hlUser");
    window.open("ChatWindow.aspx?username=" + toUsername.value, "ChatWindow", "width=350,height=250");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about asp.net, but looks like you have a javascript problem. Isn't `document.getElementById("hlUser")` an `<a>` element? It has no `value` attribute.

If you want to get the text element inside the `<a>` you could query the `text` property, or `innerHTML`.

```
<a id="hlUser">somevalue</a>
```

`document.getElementById('hlUser').text` will return `somevalue`

UPDATE: 
Having that `<a>` inside a repeater makes it impossible to know with confidence any `id` attribute inside it beforehand. I'd reccomend passing the `<a>` element, or `this.text` itself , or even the value using the same server-side script to the function.

UPDATE 2: I see this question might be a duplicate of [How do I pass a variable using window.open()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3927565/851811)

Comment: You are right, it has no value attribute...but how else do I pass the anchor parameter to my window.open method?

Comment: Surprisingly it doesnt return any value m8

Comment: Somehow its not grabbing the ID properly and gives me null value...ContentPlaceHolder1_repUsers_hlUser...is this the way it should be named as?

Comment: Ahh, now I see, you've got that `<a>` inside a repeater. So you can't know any ID inside it beforehand. Have you tried passing `this` to the function and accessing `text` in there? Or passing `<%# Eval("Username") %>` as a parameter to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the & to a +:

```
function OpenWindow() {
        var toUsername = document.getElementById("hlUser");
        window.open("ChatWindow.aspx?username=" + toUsername.value, "ChatWindow", "width=350,height=250");
        return null;
    }
```

At this level of code, you're working in Javascript rather than VB, and VB's use of & for concatenation is an oddity among programming languages.